# OAUTH client secret security, localhost redirect URI and impersonation

Tags: security, oauth-2.0

I've been doing some work with OAUTH 2 in the last few years. I have a few authorization servers and several clients using them.

Anyone who has made an app or some client solution that uses OAUTH2 knows that the client secret can be a problem. One can mitigate this somewhat by using access code grant. There has been talk about using a proxy for the secret.

My question is about the redirect URI - this was meant to protect the Access Code grant process. The Auth server will only return the access code to the redirect that is on file (in the database for that client ID). The issue comes into play with mobile apps. They usually depends on https://127.0.0.1 or https://localhost for a redirect URI. Anyone can get a localhost token, right?

With this being the case, what is stopping someone from impersonating a clientID using the localhost redirect URI? Could I not make a copy-cat app, use the same OAUTH2 sign in flow using the real client ID and if I was able to get a user to login, I now have an OAUTH token to access resource servers with. Am I wrong?

If anyone can shed more light on this, I would be greatly appreciative. I want to learn as much as possible, anything helps.

Answer (score 11):

The attack that you describe is a known weakness when using the Authorization Code grant for native mobile apps. An OAuth 2.0 extension called "Proof Key for Code Exchange" has been developed to mitigate against this threat through the use of a "code verifier" that is dynamically generated and only known by the real Client.

This work was standardized in the IETF as an RFC called Proof Key for Code Exchange by OAuth Public Clients, available at: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7636

Comment: Very helpful. I did not know about this. I will check it out. Thanks!!

Comment: After reading the RFC, this is the solution I was looking for. Thanks!!

Comment: But what If I reverse engineer the app and get its client_id + redirect URI? How will the PKCE protect against that if I use that data in another application that I develop?

Comment: you don't even need to reverse engineer an app to get its client_id + redirect URI... the point of PKCE is that it uses a secret (challenge) that is generated on the fly, only available in volatile memory

Comment: Right, but on a public app we need to use the client_id + redirect_uri in order to call the authorization server. If someone gets those values, they could add them to their app and impersonate my app, right? You are talking about authorization code interception attack, I'm talking about app impersonation by using the same client_id + redirect_uri in another app (that "stole" that data by reverse engineering mine).

Comment: PKCE doesn't protect against client impersonation. I too would like to hear more information about protecting native clients when an https redirect is unavailable.

Comment: @Joel what would be the difference if you redirect to an HTTPS instead of HTTP?

Comment: I can't say with certainty, but the point I meant to make is that when redirect URLs are semi-secure (ie. windows has more safeguards around the http and https protocols, so it is presumed they are using a reputable browser, which will indeed connect to the website associated with that address), then PKCE ensures the client *is* the expected one.

This falls apart when the redirect URL is either to localhost or to a custom protocol (eg. myapp://callback), as another app can easily set itself to be the target of that address.

Comment: And with HTTPS another app cannot set itself to be the target of that address? I mean the other app could be using my client_id and redirect_uri to get that token after the user authenticates on their app (the only way to go around this is if the user verifies on the consent screen that the name of the client doesn't match the app they're using, I guess).